# iOS CryptoKit for AES256 GCM encrypt ok but decrypt fail

Tags: ios, swift, aes-gcm, apple-cryptokit, cryptokit

I'm implementing AES256 GCM encrypt and decrypt using Swift CryptoKit, and I used this website (https://www.lddgo.net/en/encrypt/aes) to verify my results. [image] [image] At present, it seems that the encryption result is the same as the website, but the decryption keeps failing when code running on "AES.GCM.open", the error message is :"Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: CryptoKit.CryptoKitError.authenticationFailure". However, I print out the ciphertext, tag, and iv from the sealedBox. These values seems look correct. I don't know where I am going wrong, can someone help me? Below is my completed code.

```swift
import UIKit
import CryptoKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let STOKEN = "34567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF12"
    let UDID = "ABCDEF12-34567890ABCDEF12"
    let S1 = "c5f2aca59ffc9575"
    var outputResult: String?
    var decryptStr : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let inputContent = "\(S1),\(UDID)"
        let stokenSha256String = genSha256Data(STOKEN)
        
        outputResult = encrypt(stokenSha256String, calString: inputContent)
        guard let encryptResult = outputResult else { return }
        //EnResult:1893c92900a68a5456aec3c2c2f2a224a6a97e33835b54abc0accd1fd200357bdbb814f22f70807167c8cb34f71538e32e248e6624f89e6b659b
        print("EncryptResult: \(encryptResult)" )
        
        decryptStr = decrypt(stokenSha256String, r1: encryptResult)
        guard let decryption = decryptStr else { return }
        print("DeCode: \(decryption)" )
    }

    func genSha256Data(_ value: String) -> String {
        if let data = value.data(using: .utf8) {
            let hash = SHA256.hash(data: data)
            let hashString = hash.compactMap { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
            return hashString
        }
        return ""
    }

    func encrypt(_ key: String, calString: String) -> String {
        let tmpShar256Result = genSha256Data(key)
        let password = String(tmpShar256Result.prefix(32))
        let ivStr = String(tmpShar256Result.prefix(48)).suffix(16)
        guard let ivData = ivStr.data(using: .utf8) else { return "Fail" }
        let newIV = try! AES.GCM.Nonce(data: ivData)
        let passwordData = Data(password.utf8)
        let calStrData = Data(calString.utf8)
        let sealedBox = try! AES.GCM.seal(calStrData, using: SymmetricKey(data: passwordData), nonce: newIV)
        let sealDataStr = sealedBox.ciphertext.toHexString()
        let tagDataStr = sealedBox.tag.toHexString()
        let resultStr = sealDataStr + tagDataStr
        return resultStr
    }
    
    func decrypt(_ key: String,  r1: String) -> String {
        let tmpShar256Result = genSha256Data(key)
        let password = String(tmpShar256Result.prefix(32))
        let ivStr = String(tmpShar256Result.prefix(48)).suffix(16)
        guard let ivData = ivStr.data(using: .utf8) else { return "Fail" }
        let newIV = try! AES.GCM.Nonce(data: ivData)
        let passwordData = Data(password.utf8)
        let r1Data = Data(hexString: r1)!
        //let sealedBox = try! AES.GCM.SealedBox(combined: r1Data!)
        let tagData = Data(hexString: "cb34f71538e32e248e6624f89e6b659b")//cb34f71538e32e248e6624f89e6b659b
        let sealedBox = try! AES.GCM.SealedBox(nonce: newIV, ciphertext: r1Data, tag: tagData!)
        print(sealedBox.ciphertext.toHexString())
        print(sealedBox.tag.toHexString())

        let ivHexText = Data(sealedBox.nonce).toHexString()
        if let ivString = String(data: Data(hexString: ivHexText) ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8) {
            print("iv String: \(ivString)")
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
        let decrypted = try! AES.GCM.open(sealedBox, using: SymmetricKey(data: passwordData))
        let decryptedString = String(data: decrypted, encoding: .utf8)
        
        return decryptedString!
    }
}

extension Data {
    init?(hexString: String) {
            let trimmedString = hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            var data = Data(capacity: trimmedString.count / 2)

            var index = trimmedString.startIndex
            while index < trimmedString.endIndex {
                let nextIndex = trimmedString.index(index, offsetBy: 2)
                let byteString = trimmedString[index..<nextIndex]
                if let byte = UInt8(byteString, radix: 16) {
                    data.append(byte)
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
                index = nextIndex
            }

            self = data
        }
    func toHexString() -> String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }
    
}
```

My expectation is to get the original encrypted content from decryption,
Input Content for decryption: "1893c92900a68a5456aec3c2c2f2a224a6a97e33835b54abc0accd1fd200357bdbb814f22f70807167c89db3b0ded152c87fe13ba9a4e4cc749d8b6d",
Password when decrypt:
"92cc6afef35b52e0bbaca4307de3c151",
IV when decrypt:c3f64cc013d39d6f,
the output result(before encrypted) should be "c5f2aca59ffc9575,ABCDEF12-34567890ABCDEF12".

Website Result : [image: https://www.lddgo.net/en/encrypt/aes]